# FFMPEG - Combine multiple audio files and one video in to the multi language video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've checked if there was a thread like this one, but seems like either there was none or i suck at searching.
Anyways, to the the point.

I wanted to create a video file with different audio tracks where every audio track is basically same but in different lanugage. I've got five audio tracks in *.wav, and I need to combine them with video so the output file will be a video where user will be able to choose on of the 5 available audio tracks to play along with the video, like language selection in dvd.
I'm not sure if should i try the 'map', 'concat', or something totally different?

Appreciate any help with that.

Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio1 -i audio2 -i audio3 -i audio4 -i audio5 \
-map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a -map 3:a -map 4:a -map 5:a \
-metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:0 title="Title 1" \
-metadata:s:a:1 language=sme -metadata:s:a:1 title="Title 2" \
-metadata:s:a:2 language=ipk -metadata:s:a:2 title="Title 3" \
-metadata:s:a:3 language=nob -metadata:s:a:3 title="Title 4" \
-metadata:s:a:4 language=swa -metadata:s:a:4 title="Title 5" \
-c:v copy -c:a libopus output.mkv
```

- In this case you can't rely on the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior, so use the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to choose each desired stream.
- You can set the language and/or title metadata for each audio stream. See [ISO 639-2/T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) for the 3 letter code.
- This example will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the video instead of re-encoding it.
- You did not specify the required output formats, so I just chose the encoder libopus and Matroska output container format.

Comment: Thanks mate, after tiny polishment (deleteing -map 6:a) everything workes superb. Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gamba Thanks. `-map 6:a` wasn't supposed to be there. Fixed in answer.

Comment: @Gamba Edited answer with title metadata. VLC will display this info.

Comment: If you need to combine all the streams from all the files, you can omit stream types: `-map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 -map 5`